# How to inflate  two layout in  custom  list view row for separator in android

Tags: android

How to inflate  two layout in  custom  list view row for separator in android.can anybody provide example

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

with the `divider` and `dividerHeight` properties. For instance:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:divider="@android:color/black"
  android:dividerHeight="5dip" />
```